# I want to create a loop, that collects the first item and last item of each array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$store = [
    ["Call of Duty", "Shooter", 59.95],
    ["Rocket League", "Sport", 19.95],
    ["Assassins Creed", "RP", 49.95]
];

$x = 1;
$length = count($store);

foreach ($store as $info) {
    if ($x === 1) {
        //first item
        echo $info;
    } else if ($x === $length) {
        //last item
        echo $info;
    }
    $x++;
}
?>
```

here's my code. What I want to achieve is to create a loop that collect every first item of each array, and also every last item of each array.

So when I run the program, it gives me "Call of duty 59.95" "Rocket League 19.95" "Assassins Creed 49.95".

Now the program only returns "ArrayArray" because all the 3 arrays are stored in one array, so it gives me the first array and last array as a result. But I want it to go inside those arrays and collect the first and last value from there. How do I achieve this?

Comment: foreach ($store as $info) {
    `echo $info[0].' '.$info[count($info)-1];`
    echo '\n';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the first `[0]` and last `[count($info]-1]` of the `$info` array in each iteration round your loop

```
$store = [
    ["Call of Duty", "Shooter", 59.95],
    ["Rocket League", "Sport", 19.95],
    ["Assassins Creed", "RP", 49.95]
];

$tot = 0;
$nameBuf = '';

foreach ($store as $info) {
    echo $info[0] . ' ' . $info[count($info)-1] . PHP_EOL;    
    $tot += $info[count($info)-1];
    $nameBuf .= $info[0];
}
echo 'Total price   = ' . $tot . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Total letters = ' . strlen($nameBuf) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Avg letters per name = ' . strlen($nameBuf)/count($store);
```

RESULT

```
Call of Duty 59.95
Rocket League 19.95
Assassins Creed 49.95
Total price   = 129.85
Total letters = 40
Avg letters per name = 13.333333333333
```

Comment: Great! This helped me save so much time, because I didn't find any solutions online.

Comment: And not to be constantly asking question, but my exercise tells me to tell the average price out of the total, I got that one myself since I already knew how to do that. But in that loop we collected all the names of the games. I don't know really where we store that data, or maybe we don't even store it at all. But now I only need the length off all those strings and then get the average length of them. I recently did this, but since I didn't knew that I had to use a loop, it's being quite difficult for me.

Comment: there you go,you can lookup [`round()` in the manual for yourself](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: Haha, no that's not what I meant, I know how to round those numbers for example that total you gave me, but now I only need to store all those game name in a variable as we loop through each array, and then count them all up, which me can maybe do using a strlen(); and then I gotta get the average number of characters that have been used. I can do that by myself, I only need to know how I can store all those names or strings in 1 variable. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Thats a real wierd requirement, but I think I understood what you were asked to do, this time

Comment: OMG yes! that's really how to do it! I want to thank you so much! Can you tell me how you did it, or what the ".=" means, so I can learn from it and remember it for the next time ;)

Comment: `.=` is a concatenator, equivalent to `$var = $var . $otherVar`

Answer (score 1):

Try [reset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [end](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($store as $info) {
  echo reset($info).' / '.end($info).'<br>';
  $total += array_sum($info);
}
echo count($store).' '.$total;
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work. I do have another question for this. Now that we got all the prices out of the array, how do we make a calculation and count these all up? Is it possible to do this in the foreach-loop itself?

Comment: This indeed worked as well, thank you for your help!